# How to support nested subgraph using JUNG

Tags: java, layout, graph, jung

Does Jung support nested subgraph like Graphviz fdp layout? The link is: http://www.graphviz.org/content/fdpclust

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly in the same way, but yes: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/SubLayoutDemo.html

Comment: I run it, it seems that one subgraph can overlap another subgraph/parentGraph. Is it true? I want to draw subgraph with border and fill its background, it can not be accepted if some subgraphs overlap others. Is this can be implemented using JUNG?

Comment: Out of the box, no.  With some additional work, yes.  If this is for a single graph which is not too large, you can move things around by hand; otherwise you'll need to provide your own layout algorithm or adapt an existing one.  The extra rendering bits (borders, background fills) are up to you, although we provide pre-post rendering Paintables to draw them on (see our demos for examples).